# How can I use a function pointer instead of a switch statement?

Tags: switch-statement, function-pointers

How can I use a function pointer instead of a switch statement?

Comment: What language? What are you trying to accomplish? Is this a homework question?

Comment: What language are you writing in?

Answer (score 7):

A slightly different approach from the link posted by ars: You can use the value from the switch statement as an array index in an array of function pointers. So instead of writing

```
switch (i) {
    case 0: foo(); break;
    case 1: bar(); break;
    case 2: baz(); break;
}
```

you can do this

```
typedef void (*func)();
func fpointers[] = {foo, bar, baz};
fpointers[i]();
```

Alternatively you can use the function pointers instead of numbers as described in ars's answer.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a page that does a pretty good job of explaining this in C++:

- http://oopweb.com/CPP/Documents/FunctionPointers/Volume/CCPP/FPT/em_fpt.html

**EDIT:**

Above link is broken as of June 2020. Cached here:

https://web.archive.org/web/20170606042951/http://oopweb.com/CPP/Documents/FunctionPointers/Volume/CCPP/FPT/em_fpt.html

Comment: I had to +1 this just because that's such a good reference. I don't see the need to explain it all over again when someone else has already done it. Thanks.